# InvalidOperationException when use LINQ with List

Tags: asp.net, .net, list, linq, asp.net-core

I want to change my code to use LINQ.

My previous code here is working:

```
// Remove unselected features
var removedFeatures = new List<VehicleFeature>();
foreach(var f in v.Features)
  if(!vr.Features.Contains(f.FeatureId))
     removedFeatures.Add(f);
```

When I refactor it to LINQ like this:

```
 var removedFeatures=v.Features.Where(f=>!vr.Features.Contains(f.FeatureId));
 foreach(var f in removedFeatures)
    v.Features.Remove(f);
```

I get the exception below:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)

I know it means my code modified a list when the list is iterated, but I don't know where this error happened?

Comment: You cannot modify the same collection inside a foreach. try for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: But I didn't modify the list iterated. The list I iterate is removedfeatures but the list I modify is v

Comment: removedfeatures is actually referring to v.Features. Any changes to removedFeatures is actually altering v.Features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var removedFeatures=v.Features.Where(f=>!vr.Features.Contains(f.FeatureId));
foreach(var f in removedFeatures)
   v.Features.Remove(f);
```

`removedFeatures` is just an iterator, not a list.  When the foreach runs, it basically says "get me the next item to meet the criteria".  That's the first time the Where() is executed. So, if the first one is removed, the `v.Features` list is changed.

```
var removedFeatures=v.Features
                     .Where(f=>!vr.Features.Contains(f.FeatureId))
                     .ToList();
```

By adding the `ToList()`, you're creating a separate list of the items that you wnat removed, so you never have to look into the list you are deleting from.

Answer (score 1):

You  have to make the collection enumerable instead of queryable Using ToList()

```
foreach(var f in removedFeatures.ToList())
    v.Features.Remove(f);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realised my removedFeatures is collection enumerable. It does work after adding ToList().

Comment: I have another code.                                                                                                                                                  var addedFeatures = vr.Features.Where(id=> !v.Features.Any(f=>f.FeatureId==id)).Select(id=>new VehicleFeature{FeatureId=id});
                foreach(var f in addedFeatures)
                    v.Features.Add(f);                                                                                     ========================================                                                                             which is working.

Comment: Do you know why the code above is working? is it because using Add(f) is fine but using remove(f) is not fine?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `foreach` loop try `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < removedFeatures.Count; i++)
{
       v.Features.Remove(removedFeatures[i--]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or even simpler

```
var features = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var removedFeatures = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
features = features.Except(removedFeatures).ToArray();
//4, 5
```

Comment: this will work only with simple types, or if you have custom comparer in place, but it is a valid option anyway